# python return statement in an and gate

Tags: python, return, short-circuiting

I am not advocating this as a good style, I am just curious why it doesn't work (Invalid Syntax) and my search-fu is failing me.

```
def f(x):
    x and return x
    return 0
```

---

this does work in perl, e.g.:

```
sub f {
    my $x = shift;
    $x && return $x
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase as a clear question rather than just statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is a language with a distinction between statements and expressions.

`return` is a statement and it cannot be used where an expression is expected.

The opposite, as usual with languages with this duality, is instead valid because an expression can be considered a statement (so for example you can write `foo()` as a statement).

If you like one liners your code can be written as

```
return x if x else 0
```

or more simply

```
return x or 0
```

because the `or` operator returns the first operand that is "truthy" not just `True` or `False` (and also does short-circuiting, i.e. doesn't evaluate the right operand if the left operand is truthy).

Answer (score 1):

What you would want to write in python in such a case is:

```
def f(x):
    return x if x else 0
```

Or:

```
def f(x):
    return x or 0
```